# Fail to set up sso/ssl in tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, ssl, tomcat7, single-sign-on, tomcat8

I am trying to set up ssl in tomcat 8 and I followed documentation from my company which is written for tomcat 7. That documentation works fine for tomcat 7 but when I try the same thing in tomcat 8, I get the following errors in catalina.out log file. Can you please tell me what causes this error? 
by the way sso in the log file refers to a simple hello world war application that I created to test the sso/ssl.

```
    SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/sso]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1701)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:812)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/sso]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5065)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [com.sap.ldi.tomcat.extensions.SSLAuthenticatorWithFormFallback[/sso]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/deploy/LoginConfig
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2894)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.modules.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource.createManagedBean(MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource.java:297)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.modules.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource.execute(MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource.java:77)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.modules.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource.loadDescriptors(MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource.java:70)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.load(Registry.java:582)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.findManagedBean(Registry.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.registerComponent(Registry.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.register(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.initInternal(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ValveBase.initInternal(ValveBase.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.LoginConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:435)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:493)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:426)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: how did you solve the missing LoginConfig problem in tomcat 8? I'm struggling with this now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase is changed in Tomcat 8. The most important change is the method

```
public boolean authenticate(Request request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
```

You don't get the LoginConfig anymore in the parameters. It is easy to get it now:

```
LoginConfig config = context.getLoginConfig();
```

That LoginConfig has moved to another package: org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.LoginConfig.